# errors for bazel during tensorflow android building

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel

I am following this tutorial
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android

my errors after using

```
sudo bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package


ERROR: /home/hugo/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/1c2dc229a3fb3a0c8f1a06862d6b4c74/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD:4:1: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hugo/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/1c2dc229a3fb3a0c8f1a06862d6b4c74/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD", line 4
    error_gpu_disabled()
File "/home/hugo/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/1c2dc229a3fb3a0c8f1a06862d6b4c74/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/error_gpu_disabled.bzl", line 3, in error_gpu_disabled
    fail("ERROR: Building with --config=c...")
ERROR: Building with --config=cuda but TensorFlow is not configured to build with GPU support. Please re-run ./configure and enter 'Y' at the prompt to build with GPU support.
ERROR: no such target '@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain': target 'toolchain' not declared in package 'crosstool' defined by /home/hugo/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/1c2dc229a3fb3a0c8f1a06862d6b4c74/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD.
```

I also tried building with android studio, the error is

> Error:Execution failed for task ':buildExternalAssets'.
>   A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/local/bin/bazel''

I checked /usr/local/bin/ and there is no bazel folder in there.

I am assuming that the above error is also caused by my bazel not installing correctly?
I tried bazel version and got

```
Build label: 0.4.5
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Thu Mar 16 12:19:38 2017 (1489666778)
Build timestamp: 1489666778
Build timestamp as int: 1489666778
```

so I am pretty sure it is installed.
What is the error here and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Error:Execution failed for task ':buildExternalAssets'. A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/local/bin/bazel''

1.This says that bazel is not found at "/usr/local/bin/bazel" and you clearly understood that as you said, "I checked /usr/local/bin/ and there is no bazel folder in there."

2.Please check where bazel is installed on your PC by "whereis bazel" command on your command line (if on Linux OS)

PC:~$ whereis bazel

bazel: /usr/bin/bazel /etc/bazel.bazelrc

ERROR: Building with --config=cuda but TensorFlow is not configured to build with GPU support.

3.Looks like you are using sources targeted for CUDA, is that what you are trying to do? I mean do you want to compile the sources for deployement on CUDA based devices?

if so, "Please re-run ./configure"

Comment: my whereis bazel showed    bazel: /usr/bin/bazel /etc/bazel.bazelrc. I used --config=cuda because I just copy from the tutorial step by step. I looked at some posts and it looks like that line is bugged or something? I tried ./configure and it worked. thanks. I am trying ot build from android studio as well. Should I change the bazellocation variable to  /usr/bin/bazel /etc/bazel.bazelrc ??

Comment: If you are trying to build from Android Studio, please change the bazellocation variable to /usr/bin/bazel and also check if variable "def externalModelData = '../../../bazel-tensorflow-master/external'" is pointing to a valid file name. Initially build.gradle file had "def externalModelData= '../../../bazel-tensorflow/external'"

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you also happen to know which version of Inception is implemented in the Java API that is used in the demo? How do I check that (or change that if I want to)?

Comment: Yes, inception5h is used in the demo. In tensorflow root directory, there is a WORKSPACE file, in that you can find URL it uses to download inception5h. You change it, in build.gradle file in tensorflow/examples/android(check last two lines).

Comment: thanks. I can't seem to find any documentation of the architecture of Inception5h, e.g. how many layers etc. Also, have you tried implementing other inception models in android settings? If so, how is the speed of things comparing to the demo? Thanks again for being so helpful

Comment: Even I don't know much about architecture of Inception5h. I tried retraining the Inception3 model, with set of my own images i.e transfer learning. On my OnePlus3T device, demo APK was working with an inference time about 200~300ms and my retrained model APK is working about 1200~1400ms.

Comment: have you tried using some CNN compression technique to achieve a quicker speed? Also, when you say Inception3, is it the same as Inception-v3? Thanks

Comment: Yes I meant Inception V3, I quantized and stripped my retrained model. I suspect I missed optimization for inference. Can you please share more information about CNN compression. Thanks

Comment: I am just reading some papers on making CNN viable in smartphone. Most people seems to say that CNN models are too computationally intensive even for modern day smartphones, therefore compression techniques are used. There are many compression techniques e.g. quantized CNN, tensor decomposition. All the papers say that it can compress the memory overhead by 5x or so, and can speed up computation by 10 fold+, while only lossing 1% accuracy. I looked up DeepFoodCam, and they claim to be able to achieve 95% top-5 accuracy for around 250ms computational time when I test it. http://foodcam.mobi/

Comment: what do u think about that? I am a bit skeptical with how quick and accurate it is

Comment: 95% top-5 accuracy for around 250ms computational time is amazing. Tried testing the apk on my mobile, but I dont know how to find the inference time on this apk. I learnt that inception5h and inceptionV1 are the same. Since inception5h is working at inference time about 200~400ms, I am trying to retrain the inceptionV1 model.

Comment: i am assuming the inference time is the number after (Time) that is on the toast. So inception5h should be the same model in the paper 'Going deeper with convolutions' then? Where did you find that out? Thanks.

Comment: Inference time is the time taken by the model to interprit the given Image (atleast here in Inception Models, used for Image classification). I have installed the tensorflow demo application on my OnePlus3T device and on pressing the "volume up/+" key, you can check how the model is performing on the device. InceptionV5 model (comes with tensorflow demo app) worked at 200~400ms, retrained InceptionV3 worked at 1200~2700ms.

Comment: Do you happen to know if Camera1 (the old camera API) will work for the task as well? What camera API did you used to build your own demo?

Comment: I did not try using camera 1 api, the default tensorflow application uses camera2 api. I only made changes related to "retraining the Inception model, with my own data".

Comment: So it is the .pb file that you changed? From my understanding, the .pb file contains both the CNN model and the weight, while the .txt file contains the label. So does it mean that if you are replacing the .pb file to use your own training model?

Comment: I remember you said you retrained a InceptionV3, have you tried retraining 5h instead? If not, any reason why not? I googled it and it seems like retraining 5h is kind of problematic, have you run into that issue as well? Thanks again

Comment: Yes I did run into those issues, you can check out my other questions on Stackoverflow. I got a reply from Google, saying that Inception V1 is similar to Inception 5H model. But couldn't get comparable inference timings to Inception 5H model.

Answer (score 1):

There are other options also available to build native library.

You can try in build.gradle

// set to 'bazel', 'cmake', 'makefile', 'none'

def nativeBuildSystem = 'cmake'

latest version of android having capability to add cmake build tool for building native libs.

I done with cmake successfully.

Answer (score 0):

*(Tried commenting on OP's thread but have insufficient karma, so I'm posting as an answer instead.)*

The `whereis` command returned two paths, not one:

- `/usr/bin/bazel` is your bazel binary. Set that as the path to whatever variables you need to.
- `/etc/bazel.bazelrc` is the path to your bazelrc file. It's a configuration file for Bazel where you can specify commonly used flags for bazel commands, e.g. if you always build like `bazel build --flag=value //foo` then you can add an entry to this file `build --flag=value` meaning for the "build" command always use this flag by default, so you wouldn't have to type it every time. It's OK if this file is not present on your system, Bazel will still work correctly. Read more here: https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#bazelrc